# "saving as" excel file downloaded from html

Tags: html, excel, contenttype

my problem is that i'm using IE9, I use the "application/vnd.ms-excel" content type, and the file downloads correctly. My problem is that after I had downloaded the file, opened excel, and pressed "save as" button, the default format is "*.htm, *.html", and I need it to be xls. Is there any way to change that "default"? I can't upload a picture, because of my reputation

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using aspbiff8, it is easy to use, but still doesn't support text formatting (I guess). You can find it going to http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspbiff8/

If you can fomat the cells, plase share it.